# Word Document - Paragraph level Tag and Filter

Tags: microsoft-word, tags

Is there functionality within standard MS word for data tagging?

Being built around XML, it seems like there should be a way to add tags around blocks of text that would not appear when printing, but would allow a user to mark certain lines of text.  This would be particularly useful when working with templates where a master template of a document could be created, and when the template is used, the user could tailor the output by filtering out tags that are not needed.

The easiest example to explain what I'm looking for would be a document describing a house.  There could be sections such as this:

- Roof
- Walls
- - Paint
- Doors
- - Paint
- Windows
- Materials
- - Paint

Each of those tags would surround a section of the document that goes into more detail about what you want to specify about a roof, wall, etc.
Now say you want to use that template to make a shed with no windows and no paint.  Obviously under usual circumstances, you could just delete the whole window section and paint section.  However, details/requirements concerning paint are also part of the walls and doors sections.  Rather than having to manually hunt down each place paint appears, it would be nice to be able to hide anything tagged with "paint" from the template.

I have looked around but I can't seem to find how to implement this if it's possible.  It seems like some people have tried to make this work using quick-text but that seems more suited to making a library of things you want to use over and over rather than making a library of templates that you want to be able to pare down for quick use.

Comment: You can hide text ...

Comment: Hiding text isn't really what I was going for.  Word has the ability to make templates and I would like to be able to use the template as a base document and quickly pare out the sections that aren't needed through the use of filters in some capacity.  To go back to the house example, I envision having a form tied to the document (a feature built into word) that I can deselect a checkbox for the paint and all of the references to paint will be removed.